# How do I unjam the signal during the battle with Bane?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

How to unjam the jammer signal? I can't find the jamming device. I use the bat senses and see the jammer's symbol - but it seems to be in another part of the room behind a wall, during the battle with bane.

Answer (score 3):

Line up carefully, and shoot at it with the disruptor gun through the very middle. You'll see a gap. I found it tricky myself but persevere.